# Slow loading of images in a collection view, swift

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I have a few (20 - 30) images stored the app and on loading them on to a collection view, they start off small as shown in the screen shot and on scrolling they become the normal size.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Quite confused on why!

Here is my code for the cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cellSelected = iconCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("IconCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! IconCollectionViewCell

        cellSelected.workoutImage.image = iconsArray[indexPath.item].exerciseIcon

        cellSelected.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        cellSelected.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale;

        return cellSelected
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: add your code in your question

Comment: Have you set constraint of image properly ? also need to set UIImage content mode to AspectFit

Comment: @Rushisangani I have done both.

Comment: @Gugulethu Turning OFF self.layer.shouldRasterize increases performance to normal levels.

Comment: @MayankPatel Thanks. I have done that. :). Unfortunately I know it's not the solution to the problem.

Comment: Before return line put this line: cellSelected.setNeedsDisplay()

Comment: Try to set the contentMode of image view to aspectFit.

Comment: @Varun Already in that more and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {



    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell
    cell?.imageth.image = UIImage(named: (arrayName[indexPath.row] as? String)!)
    return cell!
```